# SharePoint Online Access Requests List

Tags: sharepoint-online, user, access

In SharePoint Online, there is a "Access Requests" list which manages users' access request to the site.

If a user request access while accessing site URL,in "Permission" drop down,we get all SharePoint Groups which means we can add that particular user to any of the SharePoint groups directly from that page.

Whereas if a user request access while accessing a particular page on the site, the "Permission" drop down displays only Read,Edit,Full Control which means we can provide individual user access to that particular page. Is there any option to get even the SharePoint groups while requesting access for a particular page?

Comment: Does the page in question have broken permission inheritance?

Comment: @DerekGusoff No,the page inherits permission from the library and the library inherits permission from the site.